# ggplot2: How to adequately capture spread of data in plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, data-visualization

Using Stanford's sentiment classification routine (contained in the CoreNLP toolkit), I am trying to plot the "sentiment" of each sentence in a given document. The data from the sentiment classification essentially consists of five columns and n rows:

```
0.0374 0.1311 0.1502 0.5761 0.1052
0.0117 0.0301 0.1748 0.5980 0.1854
0.1261 0.7332 0.1182 0.0156 0.0069
```

Each row represents a sentence in the file fed to the classifier, and each of the columns in that row represents the confidence intervals regarding the sentence's sentiment value: The first column contains the algorithm's confidence that the given sentence has "very negative" sentiment, the second column contains the confidence that the sentence has "somewhat negative" sentiment, the third column represents the confidence that the sentence contains "no sentiment" (i.e. is descriptive); the fourth column represents the confidence that the sentence is "positive", and the fifth column represents the confidence that the sentence is "very positive".

For each row in the data, it's easy enough to identify the column with the maximum value, and then plot those values in sequential order, using negative values if the maximum value in the row falls in the first or second columns, zero if the max is column three, and positive values if the maximum value falls in the fourth or fifth rows:

[image]

If I only plot the sentiment scores with the largest confidence values in each row, though, (which is what I've done in the plot above), I end up throwing out four of five columns of data for each row. Is it possible to represent *all* the rows of this data in a reasonably intuitive fashion using ggplot2? I realize that this question is borderline off-topic on SO, but I thought that others with more familiarity with ggplot (and dataviz more broadly) might be able to point me towards a better visualization method for my data structure. In any event, I would be eager to hear others' thoughts on this question.

Comment: Well, rather than using the maximum probability as a surrogate for sentiment, you could use the weighted average sentiment, e.g., associate a Likert scale `L=c(-2,-1,0,1,2)` with the columns and calculate the "expected sentiment", `ES = P %*% L` where `P` is your sentiment classification matrix. Then plot this vs. sentence number. You can also calculate the uncertainty in sentiment for each sentence.

Comment: I think you're right, @jlhoward, but the question I have is what value to apply to the scalars for columns 1 and 5. (Does "very negative" translate to negative * 1.5, or * 2, or ... ?) I'll need to think more about this before multiplying the numbers. The question is, though, once I have my scaled values, can and should I plot some combination of them (for each row), or should I throw away all of the columns but the one with the greatest value?

Comment: Using expected sentiment inherently incorporates a combination of all columns for each row. The scale factor does not matter as long as you believe the different between "very negative" and "negative" is the same as the difference between "negative" and "neutral", etc. If you provide your whole dataset, or a much bigger part of it, I can show you (upload it and provide a link).

Comment: Here's the data for Romeo and Juliet (one row per sentence): https://github.com/duhaime/sentiment_data/blob/master/sentiment_data.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is an expansion on my comment, using your Romeo and Juliet dataset.

Rather than using the maximum probability for each sentence as a surrogate for sentiment, you could use the weighted average, or "expected sentiment". This is calculated, for each sentence, as:

> L = [-2,-1,0,1,2]
>
> E(S<sub>i</sub>) = Σ ( p<sub>i,j</sub> × L<sub>j</sub> )

where i,j is the row,column number and L<sub>j</sub> is the jth element of L.

You could also calculate the uncertainty in sentiment for each sentence as:

> V(S<sub>i</sub>) = Σ p<sub>i,j</sub> × [ L<sub>j</sub> - E(S<sub>i</sub>) ]<sup>2</sup>

In R code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
P <- read.csv("romeo.and.juliet.txt",sep=" ")   # file you provided
P <- as.matrix(P)                               # needs to be a matrix
# calculate expected sentiment, E(s) based on Likert scale
# E(S) = sum(P_i * i)  [i in -2:2]
L <- c(-2,-1,0,1,2)    # Likert Scale
ES <- P %*% L          # E(S)
sentiment <- data.frame(n=1:length(ES),ES)
# calculate sentiment variability for each sentence
# V(S)  = sum(P_i * (i - E(s))^2)   [i in -2:2]
# SD(S) = sqrt(V(S))
LL <- matrix(rep(L,each=nrow(P)),ncol=ncol(P))
LL <- apply(LL,2,function(X)X-ES)
LL.sq <- LL^2
VS <- P %*% t(LL.sq)
SD <- sqrt(diag(VS))
sentiment$SD <- SD
# reshape for plotting w/ggplot
gg <- melt(sentiment,id="n")
ggplot(gg, aes(x=n,y=value,color=variable)) + 
  geom_point(size=1.5,alpha=.5) + 
  stat_smooth(method=loess, size=1)+
  facet_grid(variable~., scales="free_y")+
  scale_color_discrete(name="",labels=c("Expected Sentimant","Uncertainty"))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

This data looks completely random - which makes me question the classification method (is it appropriate for Elizabethan English?). Nevertheless this does illustrate the technique.

Comment: This answer is very helpful. The classifier was trained on more modern texts, and I'm using modern spelling of Shakes texts, but you're right--the data couldn't be messier. When I look at the confidence distributions for each sentence, they seem more or less agreeable, but seen in the aggregate, the data is messy. (Taking the average sentiment by scene or collection of sentences helps reveal patterns.)